# not able to show loading image before uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Mahavir Prints</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

// javascript to upload images and showing loading image[$('#lm').show();] before upload

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form#designDetailForm").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //grab all form data  
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                var x = true;
                if (designNo.value == "") {
                    alert("Please enter design no");
                    designNo.focus();
                    x = false;
                    return x;
                }

                if (designNo.value != "") {
                    var reg = /^\d+$/;

                    if (reg.test(designNo.value) == false) {
                        alert("Please enter a valid design number.Design number should  contain only numeric values.");
                        designNo.focus();
                        x = false;
                        return x;
                    }
                }

                if (designImage.value == "") {
                    alert("Please select a image for design to be uploaded.");
                    designImage.focus();
                    x = false;
                    return x;
                }

                if (x) {
                    $('#send').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#lm').show();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'designDetails',
                        data: formData,
                        type: 'post',
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var result = data;
                            if (result == 'Design number already exists for this category.' || result == 'File name already exists.Please change the name of file and then upload.') {
                            $('#failure').show();
                            $('#success').hide();
                            $('#failure').text(result);
                        } else {
                            $('#failure').hide();
                            $('#success').show();
                            $('#success').text(result);
                            $('#designNo').val('')
                            $('#designImage').val('');
                        }
                        $('#lm').hide();
                        $('#send').attr("disabled", false);
                     }
                   });
                }
            });
            $('#send').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#lm').hide();
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Add new design</h2>
        <form role="form" name="designDetailForm" id="designDetailForm"
            method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="designNo">Design No</label> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" id="designNo" name="designNo"
                    placeholder="Design No">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label> <select name="category"
                    id="dCategory" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Amercian Chiffon</option>
                    <option value="2">Nagma</option>
                    <option value="3">Soft Feel</option>
                    <option value="4">Sharmili</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="designPhoto">Design Photo</label> <input
                    class="form-control" type="file" id="designImage"
                    name="designImage" size="50" />
            </div>

            <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div id=lm style='display: none; height: 100px; position: relative;'>
            <img src='img/loading.png' style='position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin-top:-150px;' />
        </div>
         <div id="success" style="color: green;"></div>
         <div id="failure" style="color: red;" tabindex='1'></div>  
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong?.I am able to succesfully upload image.I am not able to show loading image[$('#lm').show();] before uploading.  If is place `alert("test")` after `$('#lm').show();` I am able to see loading image.
But if i remove `alert("test")` it doesn't show me loading image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by myself.

removing async:false in ajax call did the job for me.
Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This might help need changes in if condition.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#send').attr("disabled", false);
        $('#lm').hide();
        $("form#designDetailForm").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //grab all form data  
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            var x = true;
            if (designNo.value == "") {
                alert("Please enter design no");
                designNo.focus();
                x = false;
                return x;
            }

            if (designNo.value != "") {
                var reg = /^\d+$/;

                if (reg.test(designNo.value) == false) {
                    alert("Please enter a valid design number.Design number should  contain only numeric values.");
                    designNo.focus();
                    x = false;
                    return x;
                }
            }

            if (designImage.value == "") {
                alert("Please select a image for design to be uploaded.");
                designImage.focus();
                x = false;
                return x;
            }

            if (x) {
                $('#send').attr("disabled", true);
                $('#lm').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'designDetails',
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'post',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var result = data;
                        if (result == 'Design number already exists for this category.' || result == 'File name already exists.Please change the name of file and then upload.') {
                        $('#failure').show();
                        $('#success').hide();
                        $('#failure').text(result);
                    } else {
                        $('#failure').hide();
                        $('#success').show();
                        $('#success').text(result);
                        $('#designNo').val('')
                        $('#designImage').val('');
                    }
                    $('#lm').hide();
                    $('#send').attr("disabled", false);
                 }
               });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: u cannot place $('#lm').show(); as you have shown.It shows error.

Comment: Oh yes @Ankit. Thanks for review.   The  " $('#lm').show(); " should go on top top the Ajax call, and in success you can hide the image. I have modified the answer

Comment: this is what i have mentioned in the question and it is not working. please review the question properly.

Comment: Move your default $('#lm').hide(); to the top i.e. before submit function, and try it once. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Ankit you can also use complete event for the ajax. Please refer 
https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/. Inside complete event you hide the image, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeSend`.

```
if (x) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'designDetails',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#send').attr("disabled", true);
      $('#lm').show();
    }
    success: function(data) {
      var result = data;
      if (result == 'Design number already exists for this category.' || result == 'File name already exists.Please change the name of file and then upload.') {
        $('#failure').show();
        $('#success').hide();
        $('#failure').text(result);

      } else {
        $('#failure').hide();
        $('#success').show();
        $('#success').text(result);
        $('#designNo').val('')
        $('#designImage').val('');
      }
      $('#lm').hide();
      $('#send').attr("disabled", false);

    }
  });
}
```